# editing a text file packed in android apk

Tags: android, text, edit, apk

i am using a properties file to get urls to call web services in my app. Is there a way to edit that through some android activity.
The properties file is in src/resources folder. i am accessing that file using Resourcebundle.

Answer (score 2):

You cant edit any file in application pkg file, however you can have following options to achieve this:

1. Have Preferences, if when you fetched preferences are null, load preferences with that property file, else let it be as it is.
2. Edit values in preferences.

If you still insist to use a text file only, copy property file to filesystem, and edit that file whatever you want to edit.